# Asynctask in service with an 'onPostExecute' error

Tags: android, service, android-asynctask, nullpointerexception

Consider:

```
Error : NullPointerException
        can't get data in onPostExecute();
```

I create an AsyncTask in `onStartCommand()` of a Service;

After startService:

1. `LoadDataFromNetwork.getData` runs in `doInBackground`. This method will get data from the Internet. It can be work, and I can see the Log;
2. I can't get data in `onPostExcute();`

   Why?
3. Error image

   [image]
4. Code:

   ```
    public class Service_LoadAndStoreData extends Service {

        @Override
        public void onCreate() {
            super.onCreate();
        }

        @Override
        public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

            Log.d(Application.TAG , "service start");
            new AsyncTask<Void ,Void ,List<ChannelBeans>>(){
                @Override
                protected List<ChannelBeans> doInBackground(Void... params) {
                    return LoadDataFromNetwork.getData();//it can be work
                }

                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(List<ChannelBeans> channelBeanses) {
                    super.onPostExecute(channelBeanses);
                    Log.d(Application.TAG , channelBeanses.toString()); //Error :NullPointerException;
                }
            }.execute();

            return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
        }

        @Override
        public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
            return null;
        }
    }
   ```

Comment: Your getData() is returning a null list. Could you show us the code corresponding to that task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is at the getData() method from LoadDataFromNetwork class, I think.

Comment: I want do two task in service

Comment: 1.get data from network   2.put data into SQLite    what should i do?

Comment: public static List<ChannelBeans> getData () {
        Wilddog wilddog = new Wilddog(url);
        wilddog.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                map = (Map<String, Object>) dataSnapshot.getValue();
                mDataList = getJsonDateFromMap(map);
                Log.d(Application.TAG , "load_completed" +mDataList.toString());
            }

Answer (score 0):

onDataChange() is a listener, and return mDataList can't get data in AsyncTask. I changed the code, and put dataList into SQLite after getJsonDataFromMap() in onDataChange. It's working.

Use:

```
public static List<ChannelBeans> getData () {
    Wilddog wilddog = new Wilddog(url);
    wilddog.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            map = (Map<String, Object>) dataSnapshot.getValue();
            mDataList = getJsonDateFromMap(map);
            Log.d(Application.TAG , "load_completed" +mDataList.toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(WilddogError wilddogError) {
            Log.d(Application.TAG , "Request Error");
        }
    });
    return mDataList;
}
```

Comment: Although this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how it answers the question would significantly improve its long-term value. Please edit your answer to add some explanation.

Comment: I got the solution: onDataChange() is a listener , return mDataList can't get data in AsyncTask , I change the code , put dataList into SQLite after getJsonDataFromMap() in onDataChange, it's work , thank you guys!